# How to register modules for advanced functions

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, function-module

When I select Web/Functions in the menu of typo3 cms 9.5.4 backend, I get this error:

> Advanced functions
>
> No modules have been registered. Please contact your system administrator.

I *am* the system administrator.  I can't find anywhere how to register modules.  How do I register any modules?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `EXT:wizard_crpages` and `EXT:wizard_sortpages` are not maintained anymore in TYPO3 9.x.

`EXT:func` has been moved to the [TYPO3 Extension Repository](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/func/) to preserve the possibility to register your own wizards.

UPDATE:

The possibility to create multiple pages and to sort pages is now available via the context menu in the page tree. Just do a left or right click on the icon in front of any page and choose `More options ...` from the context menu.

Comment: You could add the information that these wizards are still available in TYPO3 v9. They can now be found inside the page tree modal (right click on page, 'More options ...').

Answer (score 0):

Like Peter wrote, the Extension func was removed from core, is actually not marked as compatible with version 9.5. and should avoided to use further more.

But follow two files will help you to register your own module:

*ext/extension/ext_tables.php*

```
// Module wizard
if (TYPO3_MODE === 'BE') {
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::insertModuleFunction(
        'web_func',
        \Vendor\Extension\MyModuleFunction::class,
        null,
        'LLL:EXT:extension/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_module.xlf:mymodulefunction'
    );
}
```

*ext/extension/Classes/MyModuleFunction.php*

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension;

class MyModuleFunction
{

    /**
     * Initialize the object
     *
     * @param \object $pObj A reference to the parent (calling) object
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     */
    public function init($pObj)
    {
        // Required method
    }

    /**
     * Checking for first level external objects
     */
    public function checkExtObj()
    {
        // Required method
    }

    /**
     * Main function creating the content for the module.
     *
     * @return string HTML content for the module, actually a "section" made through the parent object in $this->pObj
     */
    public function main()
    {
        return '<h1>My module function</h1>';
    }
}
```